# Can you set the Instance ID of a new BPMN Process Instance?

Tags: wso2

I can now start a new BPMN process using the REST API. What I did notice is that I do not set the Instance ID. I get that value in the return. Is it possible to set the ID ? We use that as the primary key on other places. So I would like to be able to tell the BPMN what ID to use for the instance of the process. It seems I am getting random numbers coming back.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it seems you can set the BusinessKey to a value that you know end search with it. So it is similar to what I what.